# linksys WRT54GS logging

Tags: router

Not finding much googling, but I am trying to view logs for a linksys wrt54gs wireless router. I have enabled logging on the router, but I have no option for changing the destination address or port. I would also not like to have to view what apparently are just temporary logs through the web interface.

Does this router not support logging this way? Do I need to upgrade my firmware?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation to confirm but I'm pretty sure you can't send events to a syslog server w/ that unit.  Depending on your hardware version, check out DD-WRT or Tomato.  Both are alternate firmware that may work on that router.  A failed DD-WRT/Tomato upgrade can brick the unit, proceed at your own risk.

Comment: I was looking into DD-WRT and have confirmed that it does work on my hardware model. Just got to set aside the time now..

Answer (score 0):

The wrt54G I have sends out snmp traps. There used to be a logviewer you could download to view the logs, or failing that, just set up a machine to listen for snmp traps that are broadcast from the wrt54g to the local broadcast address.